# How to run a controller from a helper. Zend Framework 1.12

Tags: php, zend-framework

I understand that this isn't true way!
But tell me, how can I run other module->controller from action helper?
Or give me other way!

I have an api module, and need run that api module from helper with prepared request params.
Do you have any thoughts about this?

Into an Action_Helper I try to apply this code:

```
require_once "../../modules/somemodule/controllers/SomeController.php";
$ctrl = new Somemodule_SomeController($request, $response);
$ctrl->run();
```

But get error:

```
Fatal error:  require_once(): Failed opening required '../../modules/somemodule/controllers/SomeController.php' (include_path='..') in /path/to/helper/action
```

**SOLUTION**

If we ask a question on another

> How to run a controller from another controller?

We've got an answer =)
Into an Action Helper

```
$that = $this->getActionController();
$that->forward("someAction", "someController", "someModule", $params);
```

Comment: You should write you're solution in an answer and valid it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we ask a question on another

> How to run a controller from another controller?

We've got an answer =)
Into an Action Helper

```
$that = $this->getActionController();
$that->forward("someAction", "someController", "someModule", $params);
```